# Angular Material - No provider for DropListRef

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a Angular 11 project and I want to use the drag and drop from Material.

It works well but I would like to customize it a bit.

I wanted to use the Class DropListRef to make the container horizontal as it seems that css does not work on the drag and drop module, at least, now how I want it.

But when I inject in the constructor the DropListRef, I have access to its method but I have an error that says that no provider is provided (pun intended) for it.

And when I put the DropListRef in the ngModule Provider array, it returns an error (as I understand it, Class are not supposed to be put in the provider).

Though I do not know how to make it work.

If someone can help me.

```
constructor(public contentService: ContentService, private papa: Papa, private dropListRef: DropListRef) {
     this.csvForm = new FormGroup({});
     this.dropListRef.withDirection('ltr').withOrientation('horizontal');
}
```

As requested, here is a StackBlitz with the issues :

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-9smng4?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts

If we remove the DropListRef from the providers, we get the second error.

Cheers

Comment: It would be easier to have a look at the problem if you provided a
[minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)
You can set one up over at [stackblitz](https://www.stackblitz.com).

Comment: Also classes can be provided if they have the `@Injectable` decorator, aka - they are a service.

Comment: Added a stackblitz as requested.

Comment: Seems like this class cannot be injected through DI, it's probably not meant to be used externally

Comment: How can I use the API then ? Those methods are available if I call the call in the constructor. Should I use ViewChild ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `cdkDropListOrientation` input from Angular Material - [CdkDropList](https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/api#CdkDropList) to set the orientation to horizontal.

> @Input('cdkDropListOrientation')
>
> orientation: DropListOrientation
>
> Direction in which the list is oriented.

The drag and drop [examples](https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/examples) section include one for `Drag&Drop horizontal sorting` ([Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/angular/qvbjvdkkdyg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcdk-drag-drop-horizontal-sorting-example.ts)) too. Note the css settings in the example too.

E.g. from the Stackblitz:

```
    <div cdkDropListOrientation="horizontal" cdkDropList #todoList="cdkDropList" [cdkDropListData]="todo"
        [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="[doneList]" class="example-list" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
        <div class="example-box" *ngFor="let item of todo" cdkDrag>{{item}}</div>
    </div>
```